# Do I need to follow Islam because my father or forefather followed it?

Tags: freedom-of-belief

The call towards Islam in most of the prophet stories is not to follow what your father or forefathers worshiped blindly. My fathers and forefathers were following Islam and I think they are following it blindly just because their parents did it. Now, it is almost impossible to figure out the true religion because there is so much literature in different religions and most of it is hard to understand including the Quran. Reading the Quran and some of the other religious books confuses me more than making me understand as I cannot completely agree with one or other. Here are some of the choices and there may be more:

1. I am Muslim and just follow Islam blindly believing it is true religion.
2. Research all religions and try to figure out true religion. With my own limits, I believe it is almost impossible for me.
3. Believe in humanity and do not think about any religion. This is an easy thing to do but not sure it is right to do.

I may sound weird with this question but I believe the scholar/people here will provide some good perspective and clear some of my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I come from a background that is very different from most people, my mother is Catholic and my father is a Muslim (they are not married) unfortunately. But I have grew up in a confusing situation and learnt from both sides of two very strict yet similar religions therefore even though I am still learning myself and trying to grow in my relationship with Allah I feel like I am a good person to be able to help you figure this out.
I grew up with both parents also blindly following there religions and both seemed to “pick and choose” what they like to do but fortunately (even though I am still not perfect) I chose Islam.
To me there are so many clear signs!

First of all- there has to be a God!! Who do you think created the planets, the universe, day time, night time everything in life you are looking at right now! If you really think about it deep down you know that there is a God and only One God could be capable of all these amazing beautiful things that has all been created for us then you have to be grateful to Allah.

Secondly - if you are looking in to the three biggest religions Judaism, Christianity and Islam then you will see that they came in an order and that Islam was perfected for us, for example in Christianity people started to associate Jesus with Allah and so on and that is a major sin to associate anything with Allah. so Islam was perfected for us as people began making mistakes prior to that.

Thirdly- I am not here to judge or make you feel bad because I truly know how it feels it’s especially been difficult for me as I could of chose the “easier” route and followed Christianity but you can not ignore the signs just keep researching, try reading the Quran even in English so you understand it more clearly. pray to Allah to bring you closer to him and have FAITH. Remember that this life is nothing compared to the afterlife and if you choose to ignore Allah now then you will be making a big mistake. 
I think my Father and other people including myself find it so difficult as well because when you are reading the Quran you see so many things that are sins that you may have committed and it hurts and you instantly feel like a failure in some way and it’s far to easy to try and ignore it and live a life free of religion- but I believe that feeling is fearing Allah and that’s how I look at it and then that makes me feel better because I have to fear Allah and that’s how I know that I am a believer. 
The fact that there are so many religions does make it difficult but I believe that it is because this life is full of tests and trials.

I hope I could help & feel free to ask me anything because I know it’s hard to talk about this especially to people who have been lucky enough to grown up in a stricter Muslim background. 
(Also I hope that I haven’t made any false statements as I am trying to learn more myself) 
Just have faith!